# Syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Tags: laravel

I got this error in Laravel:

```
ErrorException thrown with message "syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\posts\view.blade.php)"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\storage\framework\views\84082f7931aeac789ccd4bfb975980dd81818f2a.php:16
```

And here is the code of view.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8 text-center">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Post View</div>

                <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-md-4">
<!--                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @if(count($categories) > 0)
                                @foreach($categories->all() as $category)
                                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href='{{ url("category/{$category->id") }}'>{{$category->category}}</a></li>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                <p>No Category Found!</p>
                            @endif
                        </ul> -->

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Add your code block as well, refer `how to ask` page.

Comment: Sajid Bhai : share the code which is giving this error ? from `posts\view.blade.php` ?

Comment: Hi @C2486 Please check my post again, now I add the code of view.blade.php

Comment: @RedBoy Now check my post again...thanks!

Comment: remove code between `<!-- ......... -->` and try ?

Comment: I tried but it shows me same error

Comment: return ($categories); from your controller to see whether you get the output

Comment: @koPytok: good edits, but if you see salutations or please-help pleading, they can simply be removed - no need to tidy them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an unmatched opening brace `{` here:

```
url("category/{$category->id")
```

I suspect this is being parsed by the Blade template system, and it is struggling to make sense of it. This is why the error comes out of the cached file, rather than your own.

This sort of error can be discovered by committing the view file to version control, and then snipping away parts of it until the error no longer happens. By a process of trial and error, you can find the section that raises the exception.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...I have solved my problem, I just rewrite the whole code next time i face this type of error.